# OPENGL Two LoadIdentitys

Tags: c++, opengl, camera, lighting

When i do two glLoadIdentity(),
it looks like its 2d:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective( 90, (double)windowWidth / (double)windowHeight, 0.1, 100 );

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX);
glLoadIdentity();
Camera.Render(); // (gluLookAt)
```

But, when i remove the last one, it works, but the light seems like its moving with the camera:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective( 90, (double)windowWidth / (double)windowHeight, 0.1, 100 );

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX);
Camera.Render(); // (gluLookAt)
```

Comment: The matrices aren't reset across frames, and most matrix functions operate by multiplying the matrix on top of the stack. Without `glLoadIdentity`, your `gluLookAt` calls will 'accumulate'. (Also, obligatory "You're using old+depreciated OpenGL" warning).

Comment: [The documentation](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml) lists all the valid values for `glMatrixMode`'s parameter. Yours are not among them.

Comment: `glGetError()` is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing invalid arguments to your `glMatrixMode`.

Try passing `GL_PROJECTION`**/**`GL_MODELVIEW` instead of `GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX`**/**`GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX` to them.